# gridview dynamic image change in imagebutton

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview containing some data from db, and after a check I want to see a small cross/tick image in each row, due to the result of the check.How can I change the image url dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

You could either use inline statement like 
`<%#Eval("check").ToString() == "1" ? "images/checked.gif" : "images/unchceked.gif")%>`

or use a function to get the result as follows:

```
<%# getImageUrl(Eval("value")) %>
Public Function getImageUrl(ByVal value As Integer) As String
   If value = 0 Then
      Return "images/unchceked.gif"
   Else
      Return "mages/checked.gif"
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="check" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#If(Eval("check") = 1,"images/checked.gif","images/unchceked.gif") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

in form:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="check" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImageUrl(Eval("Check")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

code-behind:

```
public string GetImageUrl(object checkObject)
{
     if (checkObject!= null)
     {
          bool check;
          bool parsable = bool.Parse(checkObject.ToString(), out check);
          check= parsable ? check : false;

          return check ? "~/Media/Images/tick.png" : "~/Media/Images/untick.png";
     }

     return "~/Media/Images/none.png";
}
```