# Image on image button not displaying when changing it dynamically based on the value of a cell in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, imagebutton

I am trying to change the image displayed on the image button based on the value of a cell on a GridView . I tried the following :

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd_UserDetails" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             GridLines="None" Width="600px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnPageIndexChanging="grd_UserDetails_PageIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grd_UserDetails_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                            <Columns>
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="userId" HeaderText="UserId" ><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /></asp:BoundField>
                                   <asp:BoundField DataField="password" HeaderText="Password" ><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="UserName" ><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email Id" ></asp:BoundField>                                        


                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Active" />
                                <asp:TemplateField>

<ItemTemplate>

<asp:ImageButton ID="img_user" runat="server" CommandName="Select"

    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("status") %>' Width="20px" Height="20px" />

</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
                             </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

codebehind :

```
  protected void grd_UserDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

        {

            ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("img_user");



            if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "Active")

            {

                img.ImageUrl = "~/images/active.png ";

            }

            else

            {

                img.ImageUrl = "~/images/inactive.png ";

            }

        }

    }
```

But the image button is not displaying any image .How do i fix this. My images seem to be placed correctly in the root .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove ImageUrl='<%# Eval("status") %>' in aspx file.
2. In aspx.cs file, please try as below. 
   (I assume gridview cell[4]'s data filed name is "Status").

   ```
   ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("img_user");
   string status = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status");
   img.ImageUrl = status == "Active" ? "~/images/active.png" : "~/images/inactive.png ";
   ```

Comment: I removed ImageUrl ..like you said also I replaced the code with the one you suggested as :   protected void grd_UserDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

            {

                ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("img_user");
                string status = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status");
                img.ImageUrl = status == "Active" ? "~/images/active.png" : "~/images/inactive.png ";

                
  }

        }

Comment: But still the image is not being displayed.

Comment: Both yout code and mine should be correct. Did you check images are there in root\images\? Can you try slash to backslash like "~\images\active-inactive.png"?

Comment: Yes ..The images are in the root folder. Also I tried \\. still wont work.

Comment: Yes..Check the image in the question.

Comment: could it be a image size issue ?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is you set breackpoint on ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("img_user"); and watch value step by step.

Comment: Anyway, you can see on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229870/gridview-dynamic-image-change-in-imagebutton?rq=1

Comment: This shouldn't be image size issue.

Comment: Strange . it's not hitting the breakpoint. What could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: I don't see RowDataBound event attach to gridview. Please add OnRowDataBound="grd_UserDetails_RowDataBound" to your gridview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162491/discussion-between-anita-mathew-and-mike).

Comment: Can you try first <asp:GridView ID="grd_UserDetails" OnRowDataBound="grd_UserDetails_RowDataBound" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"....../>

Comment: That's what i did. get this :System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Make sure "Status" field is not null.

Comment: Not only Status field but also all of the field that you are using cannot be null unless you validate/check DBNull.